# Russian grammar

Tags: грамматика

I have a few questions. I am struggling with these ones and I need some help.

Are these locative, dative or genitive pluralis?

в нём (dative)?
в саду (dative)?

много цетов --> genitive pluralis? due to the много?
много овощей --> genitive pluralis? Is the -ей added in this case because it is feminine?

Comment: _в нём, в саду_ - is a locative. _Много цветов, много овощей_ are in genitive, you got that right.

Comment: большой Спасибо!

Comment: The correct way to say 'thank you very much' is 'Большо**е** спасибо!'

Comment: @Ana, please, don't be  lazy and care to give appropriate titles to your questions. "Russian grammar" is a bad title.

Comment: @Yellow sky: thanks for the correction. I highly appreciate it and your contributions and responses improves my russian language skills and boosts my motivation. The feedback, I get from you and the other gurus is lightyears from what is given in my russian class.

Comment: @shabunc: I will keep the titles more specific. Thanks for telling me what to improve.

Comment: большоe Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know about genitive, locative and dative from the comments, this is to answer your last question:

> "много овощей" --> genitive plural? Is the -ей added in this case because it is a feminine?

No.  Plural of "**овощ**" = "**овощи**".  *Regardless of gender*, plurals that end on "-**и**" often have in genitive the postfix "-**ей**".  It is ruled by the declension, not gender.  By the way, the gender of "**овощ**" is *masculine*.  Other examles:

> **Щи** (cabbage soup, masculine, no singular, 2nd declension) - genitive **щ*ей***
>   **Вещи** (from "*вещь*" "thing", feminine, 3rd declension) - genitive **вещ*ей***
>   **Родичи** (from "*родич*" "kin", masculine, 2nd declension) - genitive **родич*ей***
>   **Москвичи** (from "*москвич*" "Muscovite", masculine, 2nd declension) - genitive "**москвич*ей***"

and so on.  But

> **Тысячи** (from "*тысяча*" "thousand", feminine, 1st declension) - genitive **тысяч**
>   **Дачи** (from "*дача*" "cottage", feminine, 1st declension) - genitive "**дач**"
>   **Чащи** (from "*чаща*", "jungle, thicket", feminine, 1st declension) - genitive "**чащ**"

Note that some *2nd and 3rd declension nouns* have in *genitive plural* the "-***ей***", but *1st declension ones* in *genitive plural* have ***no postfix***.

Answer (score 0):

**В нём** - prepositional case.

**В саду** - locative case.  Some nouns require a locative case instead of prepositional after **в** and **на**, when location is described. Example:

- Дети гуляли **в лесу** - locative
- Поэт написал стихи **о лесе** -
  prepositional

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case#Russian for more information.

**Много цветов**, **много овощей** - genitive pluralis.  When the quantity is given, no matter exact or inexact (одиннадцать, пять много, несколько etc.), nominative pluralis and accusative pluralis are replaced by genitive pluralis.

- Зачем ты купил **овощи**? (accusative p.)
- Зачем ты купил так **много овощей**? (genitive p.)

Note that other cases are not replaced:
 - На столе лежит мешок с **овощами** (instrumental p.)
 - На столе лежит мешок с **несколькими овощами** (also instrumental p.)

The exeption is when the quantity ends by один (одна, одно), два (две), три, or четыре.  Then the rules are more complicated.

When the quantity ends by один (одна, одно), the noun keeps it case but becomes singular.

When the quantity ends by  два (две), три, or четыре, n.p. and a.p. are replaced by genitive **singularis**:

- Билл Гейтс купил четыре реактивных самолёта. (genitive singularis)

But if the noun is animate, and the original case is accusative rather than nominative, the number is plural!

- Вася Пупкин купил четырёх помойных котов (genitive pluralis or accusative pluralis - they are the same in this case)

Finally, if the quantity ends by один (одно, одна), the case is not changed, but the number becomes singular.

- Салман ибн Абдул-Азиз купил двадцать одну межконтинентальную баллистическую ракету (accusative singularis)